# Does Apple Still Support the Java Interface of Bonjour?

Tags: macos, bonjour

The software I'm working on uses the **Java interface of Bonjour** on Mac to discover available machines in the local network. Recently, I found that the software had a problem in Bonjour's Java interface on several Mac machines. But other Mac systems didn't have any problem.  I noticed one difference between the failing machines and the other ones - they didn't have ***/usr/lib/java/libjdns_sd.jnilib***.  After searching on the web, I found this page of Bonjour: https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/. But I couldn't find out where to download *libjdns_sd.jnilib*. Neither could I build it easily from the source code without debugging it.

I'm trying to figure out if the Java library of Bonjour is missing on some Mac machines because Apple stopped supporting it or some other reasons. So here are my questions: Does Apple still support the Java interface of Bonjour? How can some Macs have */usr/lib/java/libjdns_sd.jnilib* while others don't? Where can I download *libjdns_sd.jnilib* directly?

(The failing machines run Mac OS 10.9, 10.10, or 10.11. They have Java 1.7 or 1.8 installed.)